# Does anyone know a good C# or PHP library for converting ppt files into HTML5

Tags: c#, html, powerpoint

I whant when convert ppt or pptx file to html5 after uplading it on server.
Does anyone know a good C# or PHP library for converting?

Thanx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199659/convert-pdf-doc-ppt-to-html5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700196/doc-pdf-ppt-to-html-conversion-php-script

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be integrated / used:
http://ppt-to-html5.com/