# Script for converting PDF/.doc files into HTML

Tags: php, asp.net, pdf, file-conversion

We run a website where people upload PDF/doc files and share them (its a website for summaries of academic literature).

We want to create a preview function so people can have a look at what the file looks like before downloading it. We currently use the Google Docs widget, but the content of these widgets is within an iFrame and therefore ignored by Google.

**Question:** Is there something like a PHP script (or any other scripting language) that can convert PDF/doc into HTML?

Comment: A quick Google search turned this: http://html2pdf.fr/en/default

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700196/doc-pdf-ppt-to-html-conversion-php-script

Comment: That is a script to convert HTML to PDF, the question is for the reverse, so not sure if this is useful.

Comment: Thanks, but thats an HTML 2 PDF converter. We need the opposite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert pdf, doc, ppt to html5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199659/convert-pdf-doc-ppt-to-html5)

Comment: How about http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Intall and use abiword, like this:

AbiWord --to=html archivo.doc

you can call this command from php.